# Huge Fourier matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, sparse-matrix

I need to create a Fourier matrix in order to apply it to a huge matrix that I needed to define as sparse using spalloc. I tried:

```
F=dftmtx(N);
```

but N is too large so I can't create it.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: the Fourier matrix, by definition, is **not** sparse. You might need to create it blobk by blobk.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the DFT matrix to be sparse? If so, you are out of luck because it's not sparse. If you don't have the memory to store it, then you'll have to create rows on the fly. Why you are doing the DFT through matrix multiplication rather than using `fft()` is a better question.

Comment: I obviously don't want DTF matrix to be sparse. I want it to be big to apply it to a huge matrix defined using spalloc. I'm trying to use DTF through matrix multiplication because I can't apply fft to a matrix defined with spalloc. Sorry if I didn't explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

For each column, you can form a reduced DFT matrix by leaving out the entries that will multiply zeros. Something like

```
X = my_matrix;
c = column_index;

x = X(:,c);
N = length(x);
inds = find(x);
F = exp( -1j * 2*pi/N * (0:N-1)' * (inds-1) );
Xdft(:,c) = F * x(inds);
```

You'll have to iterate over the columns unless the zeros in the input matrix don't change column-to-column. However, the above still seems silly to me. I'd just pull off one column at a time and use `fft()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I need to use it in lsqr:

    y=lsqr(F*X,B);

so I'm not sure I can compute it column by column.

Comment: @Marta Why not? Compute it and then pass the result to  `lsqr()`. There is no reason why the multiplication would have to be specified as an input argument.

Comment: The problem is I've got a 3*10^6-by-10^6 matrix, it may be computationally prohibitive. In the other way, using y=lsqr(F*X,B), it should apply X to the vector y obtaining a column and then apply F to just one column.

Comment: @Marta I don't follow your logic. What's going to happen is that matlab will compute `F*X` and store it in local memory before calling `lsqr()`.